# Is there a way to store keys in a hashmap in the order they were created in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

I want to write a program that stores the sum of 2 numbers in an array and retrieves it in the order in which it was generated. I know that map stores the key in sorted order. Unordered_map stores the keys in an order which is definitely not based on sequence of generation.

Is there some way i can use STL to get what i want in c++ ?
Below is my code for the program. I need to find an array of 4 numbers where A+B = C+D such that all are unique and are lexicographically sorted.

Array = 1 3 3 3 3 2 2
I should get 0 1 6 7 as output but instead i am getting 1 5 2 6.

```
vector<int> Solution::equal(vector<int> &A) {
vector<int> result;
unordered_map<int,vector<vector<int>>> hash;
int n = A.size();

for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
  for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
      int sum = A[i] + A[j];
      vector<int> temp{i,j};
      if (hash.find(sum) != hash.end()) {
        hash[sum].push_back(temp);
      }
      else
        hash.insert(make_pair(sum,vector<vector<int>>{temp}));
  }
}

for(unordered_map<int,vector<vector<int>>>::iterator it=hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); it++) {
  int size = it->second.size();
  bool found = 0;
  if( size > 1) {

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        cout<<it->first<<" ";
        if (it->second[0][0] == it->second[i][0] || it->second[0][1] == it->second[i][0] || it->second[0][1] == it->second[i][1]) continue;
        result.push_back(it->second[0][0]);
        result.push_back(it->second[0][1]);
        result.push_back(it->second[i][0]);
        result.push_back(it->second[i][1]);
        found = 1;
         break;
    }
    if (found) break;
  }
}
return result; 
}
```

Comment: You could create a little struct which in addition to the actual number holds a time stamp (with sufficient resolution) or simply a global index which gets incremented when a number is created. In the hash map you would store these structs and sort by date (or index).

Comment: Have a separate `std::vector`, push a sum onto it whenever you discover it's not already in the map.